# Transit Visa Inquiry for Uzbekistan Nationality

Tags: visas, india, transit, del, uzbek-citizens

My clients are Uzbekistan Nationality. I draw two ways for them to fly from our country Yangon to UGC with MH + HY and, CZ + HY via DEL and, TAS. What I would like to know is as when return, they need to wait about 22 hours transit time at DEL airport, will they need to apply transit visa or not?

Answer (score 3):

For **a transit time of less than 24 hours, a transit visa is NOT required** when going via Delhi Indira Gandhi International airport, as long as your clients remain airside.